Spark Streaming app with RocksDB gets OOKilled on K8S
I'm running a Spark Structured Streaming application on K8S.
The application is deployed with spark-submit  --master k8s://...
Using RocksDB state backend, configuring spark.kubernetes.memoryOverheadFactor as 2, because Spark itself consumes configured executor memory and RocksDB needs additional memory for it's work.
While the application runs, memory consumption grows slowly until reached the configured limit, then keeps near the limit and after some time exceeds the limit and gets OOMKilled.
The memory consumption is displayed on the graph.

Driver memory limit is 2.5 G and the driver consumes about 1.25 Gb
On the graph there are multiple executors, a limit for an executor is 5 G and the executors are got killed time to time.
When a new executor is started in place of a killed, it starts from low memory consumption, but slowly grows to the limit and gets killed again.
I cannot know how much actual state bytes the application has, because Spark metric "State bytes" show value which are much bigger than actual memory available, but I'm sure minimal required memory to handle the workload is much less than the limit.
Another illustration: single executor application. An executor pod got killed, restarted with state from a checkpoint and continues working while consuming only fraction of previous memory.

When pod memory consumption is close to the configured limit, it gradually grows up and time to time falls down. Zooming an area near the limit:

Obviously some mechanism in Spark or RocksDB "knows" the limit and tries to keep within it, but fails at some moment.
Relevant configuration:
Spark 3.5.2 on Kubernetes
Resource configuration (for single executor app)
    --conf spark.kubernetes.memoryOverheadFactor=2 \
    --driver-cores=1 \
    --driver-memory 500m \
    --executor-memory 2g \  # + 4Gb for RocksDB because of memoryOverheadFactor
    --executor-cores 1 \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=1
Spark app conf
    "spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.providerClass" ->
      "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.RocksDBStateStoreProvider",
    "spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.rocksdb.changelogCheckpointing.enabled" -> "false"
    "spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.rocksdb.compactOnCommit" -> "true",
    "spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.rocksdb.boundedMemoryUsage" -> "true",
    "spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.rocksdb.blockSizeKB" -> "64",
    "spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.rocksdb.blockCacheSizeMB" -> "0",

I tried to alter the options above. executor-memory, executor.instances, compactOnCommit, changelogCheckpointing, boundedMemoryUsage, memoryOverheadFactor affects pace of memory growth and time until crash but basic picture remains the same.
The questions:

How this mechanism which controls the memory usage works?
Some links to docs or the sources for memory control on k8s?
How to tune this mechanism to keep memory usage 90% of the limit?

